# Script to delete folders and subfolders from a specific folder full of subfolders

Tags: windows-server-2012

I have a folder (Users) full of user folders that we use for temporary transfer between users. I want to be able schedule a script to empty the contents of the users folders without removing the user folders or changing permissions.

Is there a way to do this via a batch file? I thought originally I could use something like:

del /F \Users**.*

But that didn't work.

Please help!

And Thank you!!

Comment: What does the del command not do correctly?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're on Server 2012... you have about 0 reason to use batch.

Here, have some Powershell:

```
Foreach($_ In Get-ChildItem C:\Users -Recurse) 
{ 
    If(!$_.PSIsContainer) { Remove-Item $_.Fullname } 
}
```

That will delete all files in and under the C:\Users directory tree, but it will leave all the directories intact.

**Edit:**

How about this:

```
Foreach($_ In Get-ChildItem C:\Users)
{
    If($_.PSIsContainer)
    {
        Get-ChildItem $_.FullName -Recurse | Remove-Item
    }   
}
```

So now what we're doing is getting a list of "first-level" directories under C:\Users, and then recursively clearing out the contents of each of those folders, so in the end the only things that will be left are C:\Users and the first level of subdirectories under it.

**Edit:** Since you mentioned that you would like to understand this better, but are new to Powershell, I'll explain the above script in a little more detail.

`Get-ChildItem C:\Users` is basically just like `C:\> dir C:\Users` in DOS, but Powershell deals in and returns everything in the form of *objects*, not just simple console output.  So by the first line reading

`Foreach($_ In Get-ChildItem C:\Users)`

It means that we are going to go through a loop for each "object" that exists in C:\Users. Since we're *not* using the `-Recurse` parameter here, Powershell will only return the first-level directory listing of C:\Users and will not dig down into the subdirectories.

`If($_.PSIsContainer)` is an If statement that means "if this current object's "PSIsContainer" property is set to True, which is just a fancy way of saying "if this is a directory," then go into this if loop.

So for every subdirectory under `C:\Users`, we will enter the If loop.  So let's say `C:\Users` has three subdirectories under it: `C:\Users\joe`, `C:\Users\kate`, and `C:\Users\bill`. Those subdirectories may have any number of files and subdirectories under them.

So we will enter the If loop 3 times, so each time will look something like this:

`Get-ChildItem <C:\Users\joe> -Recurse | Remove-Item`

`Get-ChildItem <C:\Users\kate> -Recurse | Remove-Item`

`Get-ChildItem <C:\Users\bill> -Recurse | Remove-Item`

What this line does is get the contents of that subdirectory, and the `-Recurse` switch is specified so that it drills down through all the subdirectories of `joe`,`kate`, and `bill`.

Then, it takes all those child objects and *pipes* them to `Remove-Item`, and you can think of `Remove-Item` as a fancy alias for `del`. It deletes all the things.

Make sense?

Comment: Haha, awesome, however, this doesn't fully help me.

This seems to be leaving all subdirectories intact. I need to remove anything past the second level. EG:

keep /Users/Joe, but delete /Users/Joe/stuff and /Users/Joe/word.doc etc.

Comment: Edited with a new version that should suit your needs.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, and thanks for keeping cool.

I'd really like to understand this, but I'm very new to powershell.

I've copied your script, and tried testing it on a "Test" folder with random folders inside and more folders inside those. It doesn't seem to be working. 

Should this work simply by changing the path? I changed c:\Users to c:\test, as well as trying a UNC (\\server\test) path to a similar test folder. And yes, the folders exist at those locations.

Also, can you recommend a good resource to learn this?

Comment: I've tested it a couple times with PS 3 (which is the same version as yours) and it works exactly as I described. There's a free eBook at Powershell.com that's really good as a learning resource.

Comment: @protocol I have edited once more to explain exactly what Powershell is doing in the above code snippet, since you said you wanted to better understand it. Sorry if I seemed a little frustrated earlier; I was multitasking at the time and under some stress. ;)

Comment: Makes sense now. Thank you very much for the explanation, and I will definitely check out that ebook.